IBM Watson Speech to Text returning Error 503 called from Python on Windows
I am trying to call IBM Watson Speech to Text "recognize" method and keep getting Error code 503 (but have confirmed that IBM Cloud is up and running).
I am using Python on Windows
Here is the call to IBM API from Python:
with open(MyAudioFile, 'rb') as audio_file: ResultN = speech_to_text.recognize(audio=audio_file, content_type='audio/mp3', model='en-US_BroadbandModel', speaker_labels=True).get_result()

And here is what is returned:
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\IBM\SampPyth2.py", line 25, in <module>
        ResultN = speech_to_text.recognize(audio=audio_file, content_type='audio/mp3', model='en-
            US_BroadbandModel', speaker_labels=True).get_result()

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-
packages\ibm_watson\speech_to_text_v1.py", line 671, in recognize
    response = self.send(request, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-
>packages\ibm_cloud_sdk_core\base_service.py", line 362, in send
    raise ApiException(response.status_code, http_response=response)
 ibm_cloud_sdk_core.api_exception.ApiException: Error: <HTML><HEAD>
 <TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE>
 </HEAD><BODY>
 <H1>Internal Server Error - Write</H1>
 The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to
 complete your request.<P>
 Reference&#32;&#35;4&#46;3aaa2c17&#46;1730680712&#46;33c6700
 <P>https&#58;&#47;&#47;errors&#46;edgesuite&#46;net&#47;4&#46;3aaa2c17&#46;1730680712&#46;33c6700</P>
 </BODY></HTML>
 , Status code: 503

I have tried tweaking the line in various ways, tried adding a trailing '/' on the URL (per an older post here) but am unable to figure out the reason for the 503 error.
Any ideas or suggestions for resolving error would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.
Steve

This is a problem inside their API.  There might not be anything you can do to fix it.  Are you able to look at the API logs?

I don't know how to access the API logs but will see if I can find out.  In rereading the documentation, it appears that one issue was using an audio file that exceeded the size limits.  I have now gotten the script to work on smaller files. It would have been nice if the error message was more specific.  Thank you.
